# Why is this happening with discord.ext and replit?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to run discord.py but it is not working. This is the error

```
/home/runner/Mafia-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/health_check.py:23: DistributionWarning: discord.py is installed which is incompatible with nextcord. Please remove this library by using `pip3 uninstall discord.py`
  warn(message, DistributionWarning, stacklevel=0)
/home/runner/Mafia-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/health_check.py:23: DistributionWarning: discord is installed which is incompatible with nextcord. Please remove this library by using `pip3 uninstall discord`
  warn(message, DistributionWarning, stacklevel=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    async def Hello(ctx):
  File "/home/runner/Mafia-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1262, in decorator
    result = command(*args, **kwargs)(func)
  File "/home/runner/Mafia-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1432, in decorator
    raise TypeError('Callback is already a command.')
TypeError: Callback is already a command.
```

It is for a video game but is not connected.

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from discord import Member
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members=True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="~$", intents=intents)

#######Events######
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot is up and ready!")
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('ERLC'))

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  await member.send("Welcome to the mafia!")
  

######Commands#######

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
  
@client.command()
async def Hello(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Hi')

@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await member.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f"User {member} has been kicked.")
  
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send("You do not have permissions to kick.")

@client.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await member.send("You have been banned")
  await member.ban(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f"User {member} has been banned.")
  
@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send("You do not have permissions to ban.")

client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Its probably easy to fix but I can't, I have only been coding for a year. I have to add alot of details but thats all I can say.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: You have 2 `@client.command` decorators on the Hello function.